# Convert Java Pojo from Dynamic JSON

Tags: java, json, velocity

**I want to convert JSON into Java Pojo dynamically , meaning JSON structure will be change but I need to convert that JSON into Java Pojo without creating JSON POJO, is there any framework available ?

I thought about Dozzer mapper but in dozzer mapper I always need to create SRC Object POJO ,I need to avoid same.
**

Comment: You may create a HashMap of all JSON key-value pairs dynamically. Then write a POJO with HashMap as the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json into a lightweight Json generic object provided by one of the Json libraries available that provide such a direct approach.

For instance [essential-json](https://github.com/arkanovicz/essential-json) (disclaimer - I'm the author), [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/), [json-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), ...